# How to pass a Pug JSON object to client side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am trying to pass a JSON object from pug to client side JavaScript. Here's how the code is structured. I render a JSON object and pass it to Pug from my Node-Express backend. Code below:

`server.js`:

```
app.get('/myrooms', function(req, res) {
    Room.find()
        .where('_id')
        .in(user.rooms)
        .exec(function (err, records) {
            res.render('rooms/index', {myrooms : records})
        })
})
```

After that this object is available in my pug file. Now I want to pass it to a client side script. I am doing something like this in my `index.pug` file.

`index.pug`:

```
script(src='/js/play.js').
    trooms = "#{myrooms}"
```

`play.js`:

```
console.log(trooms)
```

It gives me '`troom` is not defined' error. I don't know how I can pass this object. According to some old post this was working in jade. However, I am using the pug version `2.0.0-rc.2`.

Comment: You have to out the `trooms = "#{myrooms}"` before you source the script.

Comment: Also, need to call `JSON.parse('#{myrooms}')` to convert JSON to object.

Comment: I have tried doing `JSON.parse('#{myrooms}')` that but it did not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try

```
var trooms = !{JSON.stringify(myrooms)}
```

Comment: I revert it back to older version of jade and this works. I will work with this for now