# How return the result of a function from an external javascript script to a pug file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm currently working on a little project which use pug (I discovered it just yesterday).

Here is my configuration:

**file1.pug**

```
- let resultArray = oldArray;

input(
  type='button'
  name='resultButton'
  placeholder='Click me...'
  onclick="addNumber(resultArray)"
 )

script
  include scripts/search_script.js
```

**externalScript.js**

```js
function getTotal(resultArray) {

  let result = 0;
  let newArray = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++){
    result += resultArray[i]; 
  }  

  newArray.push(result);

  return newArray;
}
```

It's just a little (weird) example of what I did.

The thing is, I was wondering if the value of `resultArray` which is in my **file1.pug** can be replaced by the value returned from the method `getTotal()` in my **externalScript.js**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a Pug JSON object to client side JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644583/how-to-pass-a-pug-json-object-to-client-side-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pug won't have access to javascript included inside a `script` tag, which will only run in browser. If you want to use the `getTotal()` function in Pug, you could include it in an [unbuffered code block](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unbuffered-code) in your Pug file like this:

```
-
  function getTotal(resultArray) {

    let result = 0;
    let newArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
      result += resultArray[i]; 
    }

    newArray.push(result);

    return newArray;
  }
```